# Getting location coordinates (latitude and longtitude) without internet on android

Tags: android, gps, location, geocoding, wifi-direct

I am developing a Wi-Fi Direct Chat Application and I need to send the co-ordinates in the chat. But I have to do this without the internet since I'm using WiFi Direct. Are there any suggestions/API or anything which can help me ?

Comment: Internet is not required for getting current location in android if GPS is turned on and permissions granted

Comment: @IndraKumarS can you please share a guide or something ? tutorial or video

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Fused Location Provider Api](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

```
private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     // ...

     fusedLocationClient = 
     LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

     fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
         .addOnSuccessListener { location : Location? ->
             // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please share the complete guide ? i am kind of new to all this. it would be very helpful if you share any link/tutorial/video or something

Comment: You can follow the tutorial in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rNYaEFl6Fms. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I although somehow got it to work, but still, it would help me in future. thank you once again.